# How can I change the default location that Scripts and Content get Written To

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'd like to change the location that Scripts and Content live from  `"~/Scripts/"`  to  `"~/Scripts/" + version + "/"` where version is a variable that gets set dynamically based on Web.config.  I've tried the following but it's not helping:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/" + version + "/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/" + version+ "/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any code for retrieving the version from the web.config

Comment: Hi Simon... I didn't include it, but here it is:  string version = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppVersion"];

Answer (score 0):

You can probably specify the version only for the file path and leave it out of the URL.

Whatever URL you specify for the bundle...

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/" + version + "/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/" + version+ "/jquery-{version}.js"));

                              ^^^ the bundle URL ^^^
```

...is what the various views need to reference in their tags. So if you dynamically create the bundle URL then you need to do this also:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/" + version + "/bundles/jquery")
```

or

```
<script src="/" + version + "/bundles/jquery"></script>
```

The bundle URL is entirely arbitrary. You can make it whatever you want, like this, and the request will be routed to return your script bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/myAwesomeJQueryBundle").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/" + version+ "/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

So there's probably no need to build the version number into the URL.

You don't need to worry about changing the URL to prevent caching either as long as you're using `@Scripts.Render` because the application will provide a unique version id in the querystring, like this:

https://yoursite.com/myAwesomeJQueryBundle?v=QfOK7KHBzkssV3c-12FMfeyPN1SXzcP1i0jSDRdWJpE1

If the files included in the bundle are different then the version ID will be different.

---

One more note: 
Unless there's some specific need (like you're requesting the bundle from another site) be sure to use `@Scripts.Render` instead of a `<script>` tag. Because the bundler provides that version ID, it also adds a cache-control header indicating that the content can be cached for *one year*.

Comment: Thanks Scott... I think that might help.  I will implement and if it works I'll upvote your solution.  Question:  I understand that having a query string on the asset files with the version forces them to be downloaded on every request and never cached.  That seems like it would have a pretty serious performance impact.  I'm guessing I'm mistaken?

Comment: The querystring is part of the URL. If the same request is made over and over with the same querystring it can be cached. That's what it's for, so that when the bundle changes, the id changes, the url changes, and now the new script gets cached. If the id changed every time *then* it wouldn't get cached.